# Nvidia drivers broken after kernel update (Ubuntu 18.04 + kernel 5)

Tags: nvidia, kernel, ubuntu-drivers

Seems I cannot boot into Ubuntu anymore after kernel is updated to version 5. Booting hangs and I have to purge Nvidia and use xorg driver in order to be able to login.

Anyone else has the same issue?

Comment: What card and driver are you using?

Comment: Yes I tried version 5 almost the same day it came out and discovered it didn't work with nvidia.

Comment: It works with my GTX 1050 Ti. I use the 390 driver, which recently got an update.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Nvidia 8300m with version 340.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix good to know I'm not the only one. Did you find a work around?

Comment: @user581580 Nah I really didn't care. My day to day kernel is `4.14 LTS` which is good for 5 years. My current version is `4.14.134`. I just like to try new stuff as it comes out and go back to what works great.

Comment: I use the drivers from the graphics-drivers ppa here: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic  I see the 340 driver got updated on 7/31 just like the 390 one did.  I'd try installing the driver from this ppa, could be a quick fix.

Comment: @OrganicMarble i have 340.107 downloaded from the "softwares and updates". Is the one from this ppa different?

Comment: Only a couple of packages were different. I don't know how critical those are to making it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, NVIDA binary drivers will need to be updated to a version that supports kernel 5.

Check out this thread for more information and some solutions, most of which are to boot back to your previous working kernel. https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/ax3msr/beware_of_kernel_50_nvidia/

You can do this easily following these instructions:
https://askubuntu.com/a/82145/981644

Comment: Just to be sure, I did a clean install and problem still persists. I now downgraded to 4.18 kernel and I can boot with Nvidia. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1):

This screenshot shows a test system of mine running the 5.0.0-23 kernel.

It has an Nvidia GeForce 8200M card and is running the 340.107 driver from the graphics [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=disco).

[image]

(This happens to be a 19.04 system, but it's running the same kernel as the new one in 18.04 LTS HWE. It's a 64 bit Ubuntu system with the LXDE desktop installed.)

Comment: I have exactly this setup and doesn't work. I even did a clean install and still the problem persists.

Comment: @user581580 I've had an enormous amount of problems with video drivers on this system. I was really surprised that this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the newest driver with Kernel v4.xx.xx and it wouldn't run.  I then installed Kernel v5.xx.xx and the driver now works/

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I might give it a try. Up till now I prevented driver from updating.